# Is venv a python module?

Tags: python-module, python-venv

In definition Python Module defined as a single file with .py extension.
But 'venv' is called as module though it is not a single python file or is it?

I am curious about what does actually mean by python module and why venv is a module from the definition perspective.

I have tried this command `python -m venv env` this command seems to be indicate venv is a module as it is prefixed by -m.

But it has raised a question in my mind if venv is a module name or not?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is and proving that claim is simple as well.

Run the following code:

```
import venv

print(venv) #Output: <module 'venv' from '/usr/lib/python3.9/venv/__init__.py'> 
# (version might differ on your end)
```

thus it's obvious that `venv` is a **Python module**.